# Installing laravel on mac os via composer

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, mamp

I need to use lavarel on mac os. I first installed MAMP. After that, following instructions on laravel.com, I installed composer globally via homebrew. Now, when I change my directory to /Applications/ MAMP/htdocs and try `composer create-project laravel/laravel myname` on the terminal, nothing happens even after half an hour.
I also tried downloading lavarel-master manually,putting the content in htdocs and `composer install` .Again nothing in .5 hour.
I have done `composer self-update` and checked `composer diag` and all is OK.
Upon trying `which php` ,i get `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php`
I also restarted mac and tried the commands again,but same result.

Please help ,I am new to php and don't know how to proceed.

PS:Upon trying `composer install` in laravel master directory the following appears on terminal:
`Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)` and then only the cursor blinks, nothing happening. Is that a trouble with my composer or laravel installation?

Comment: Posting output of composer install would be needed, in the laravel master directory

Comment: @MarcinLawniczak I do not understand you, do i need to link htdocs with laravel master directory. Earlier I had put all the content of laravel master into htdocs.

Comment: There is no need to link those. If you're just starting out, do `composer create-project laravel/laravel myname` in a directory in your home folder

Comment: The trouble is:I already tried that, and even after .5 hour no furhter processes appeared on terminal,so I aborted the process. It doesn't take so long,does it?

Comment: What is displayed? In the terminal after you run it?

Comment: Nothing at all.After i enter the command, only the cursor is displayed,(which is for processing) ,nothing else gets printed. And it continues to do so,until I abort it (with ctrl+c).

Comment: Maybe composer is just taking time to install? Try `composer install --verbose` to see what it's doing, or where it halts at.

Comment: I don't know what had initially gon wrong. But after changing the Mamp port:80, I tried the same procedure again and it worked!